# how to pass a variable from outside the stage in jenkins pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I have set an env variable "status" as true and when executing below code test2 stage is getting skipped even though I declared the env status as true. can anyone help me on this to proceed further

using Jenkins version 2.150 and its a pipeline script

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    environment{
        STATUS='TRUE'
    }
    stages {
        stage('test1') {
            steps {
                echo 'test1'
            }
        }

        stage('test2') {
            when{
                expression {
                    STATUS = 'TRUE'
                }
            }
            steps {
                input message: 'Push to env', ok: 'GO!!'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a value for your STATUS. The comparison should be done with the '==' operator. I think the example below should work.
Check the official documentation for additional infos: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

```
stage('test2') {
    when{
        expression {
            STATUS == 'TRUE'
        }
    }
```

Comment: glad to hear this! Have fun with jenkins